# How to create application with users

Tags: python, pymongo, user-registration

I'm creating a program that will allow groups of people (e.g flatmates) to manage their funds. I want people to be able to download the app and have different users that will interact with each other.
I can't seem to find a platform that will help me combine the classes and class methods (python) with an actual database/user management program.
can anyone help with directions on what I should look for?

This is a program written in Python. I wanted it to be object oriented when the users and the groups are the classes. I'm flexible with this idea.
currently I'm using vscode with pyMongo as a database but can't understand how to do the user identification and interactions there.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what your question is asking. In the first paragraph you seem to be asking "How do I use a database in Python" but in the second you confirm that you're using pyMongo to communicate with a Mongo database. Are you just confused about how to do auth?

Comment: Note that questions recommending a specific tool or technology are generally off-topic for stack overflow. Can you narrow your question to one with a specific [mcve] including what you've tried based on your own research?

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to learn about the MVC pattern of programming.

Look into Django's models. Object Relational Models (ORM) let you treat database tables as Python classes. Django has great support for Postgres using pyscopg2. Additionally it has support for Keycloak user mgmt.

You can get started with Django's built-in Auth system for managing users. It's just another table in the database =)

You don't need a NoSQL database. Deviating from SQL will make things harder for you every step of the way.